# Display PeerTracker stats, PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, hash

I'm using PeerTracker http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PeerTracker to track torrent hashes. I have a simple HTML page to display information about the tracker like its announce url. The tracker comes with announce.php and scrape.php where announce is used to tell the tracker you have a hash to be tracked and scrape is used to return stats and information on the tracker or specific hashes. I would like to be able to use scrape.php to return the total number of hashes being tracked and the total number of peers for the entire tracker. I'm pretty much stuck because I don't know the Bittorrent standard to retrieve that information and if its even implemented the same way on PeerTracker and I'm also not sure how I would call and display this information on an HTML page using scrape.php.

edit: 
So my question would be how would I take the information returned by scrape.php and display it on a HTML page

"The response of this HTTP GET method is a "text/plain" or sometimes gzip compressed document consisting of a bencoded dictionary"

When I run

```
GET -uUsSed http://Tracker.SpaceAgeMinds.com:80/scrape.php
```

on my linux machine I get the following.

```
GET http://Tracker.SpaceAgeMinds.com:80/scrape.php
User-Agent: lwp-request/5.834 libwww-perl/5.836

GET http://Tracker.SpaceAgeMinds.com:80/scrape.php --> 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 05:46:32 GMT
Server: Apache mod_qos/9.69 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Client-Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 05:46:33 GMT
Client-Peer: 184.172.188.79:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
```

If it helps:
http://www.ohloh.net/p/peertracker
http://code.google.com/p/peertracker/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29
http://Tracker.SpaceAgeMinds.com/scrape.php
or just
http://Tracker.SpaceAgeMinds.com/scrape

Comment: What is your question?  Be specific.  Read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: How would I take the information returned by scrape.php and display it on a HTML page

Comment: Start by showing us the output of a call to scrape.php, and what you want it to look like.

Comment: Well currently there is no output when I point my browser to scrape.php and there is no output when I use <?php scrap.php?> or <?php return(scrape.php) ?> inside of an html page.

Comment: Ok, then start by learning what scrape.php does, and what you need to send to it to get output from it.

Comment: "The response of this HTTP GET method is a "text/plain" or sometimes gzip compressed document consisting of a encoded dictionary"

Comment: When I run GET -uUsSed http://Tracker.SpaceAgeMinds.com:80/scrape I get the output below. am I using GET right?

GET http://Tracker.SpaceAgeMinds.com:80/scrape.php
User-Agent: lwp-request/5.834 libwww-perl/5.836

GET http://Tracker.SpaceAgeMinds.com:80/scrape.php --> 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 05:46:32 GMT
Server: Apache mod_qos/9.69 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Client-Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 05:46:33 GMT
Client-Peer: 184.172.188.79:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17

Comment: Your content length is 0.  Are you trying to display the headers instead?

Comment: While using "GET http://cpleft.com:2710/scrape > text.gz" I get a 3.3mb file. After I extract text.gz I get a text file that has "d5:filesd20:" on one line. I must be doing something wrong because the "d5:filesd20:" is partially correct but 3.3mb for one line in a text file cant be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the scrape.php will output a simple text, when called with the stats argument. For example the url

```
http://tracker.example.com/scrape.php?stats
```

will output something like this:

```
5 peers (5 seeders + 0 leechers) in 3 torrents
```

If you have another php script, you can invoke the scrape file with this command:

```
<?php include('http://tracker.example.com/scrape.php?stats') ?>
```

EDIT: I also wanted to say that you can display the output in xml or json format as well. Please reference the call below:

```
http://tracker.example.com/scrape.php?stats=xml

http://tracker.example.com/scrape.php?stats=json
```

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question perfectly. I forgot about this question because I was so frustrated about it but I’m going to revisit it now that you cleared some things up for me.